# server.tomcat.max-threads VS corePoolSize VS spring.datasource.tomcat.max

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, database-connection, threadpool

I've an Spring Boot REST async application, wanna adjust:

1. Connections threads from clients (wanna REST request go in parallel)
2. Thread numbers for @Async methods in my service tier
3. pool of connections to DB

Browsing documentations and sites found possibilities:

**corePoolSize value=... VS  server.tomcat.max-threads = ...** - What is the difference?

**spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size= ...    VS    spring.datasource.tomcat.max... = ...** - What is the difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you are using Spring Boot 2.1 and haven't changed the defaults (using Tomcat as the embedded container and Hikari as the connection pool).

### Tomcat Request Handling Threads

To modify the number of threads (tomcat by default already uses 200 so why would you need to change it!) use the properties in the `server.tomcat` namespace (those are specific for Tomcat!. So use `server.tomcat.max-threads` to control the number of request handling.

To limit the number of concurrent HTTP connections use the `server.tomcat.max-connections` (default value 10000). This is basically the processing queue which the request handling threads use to pick/steal work from.

### Number of Threads for task execution

For controlling the number of threads used by the default created `TaskExecutor` in Spring Boot 2.1 use the properties in the `spring.task.execution` namespace. So use `spring.task.execution.pool.max-threads` to set the maximum number of threads to use for `@Async`. The `spring.task.execution.pool.core-size` controls the core (minimum) pool-size. Increasing the `max-threads` property without limiting the queue size through `spring.task.execution.pool.queue-capacity` has no effect. The default queue size is unbounded and everything will not result in growing the number of threads beyond the `core-size`.

### Connection Pool properties

Finally to specify the connections for your connection pool (the default for Hikari is 10!). Use the `spring.datasource` namespace properties and specifically the one for your connection pool (default is Hikari so the ones in `spring.datasource.hikari`, the `spring.datasource.tomcat` are for the Tomcat JDBC connection pool used as default on Spring Boot before 2.0). So set the `spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size` to manage to max number of threads.

### Note

They don't have anything to do with each other and should be confused with each other as well (imho this is already clear in the reference guide that each serves a different purpose). See [Appendix A](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) of the Spring Boot Reference Guide for a list of common properties.

Comment: It is the default connection pool used by Spring Boot (as mentioned in the first line of my answer).

Comment: is connection pool solely for DB connections? what other connections does it impact? can it be separately configured for DB and other connections?