# Difference between Spring Boot ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and server.tomcat.max-threads property

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've read that number of maximum threads for a server can be specified using `server.tomcat.max-threads` in the application.properties file.

If that is the case, what is the use of specifying `maxPoolSize` in `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` if the other property is the one that defines maximum threads available to the server?

**Example code for TaskExecutor:**

```java
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
```

Comment: Those are very different things. The `server.tomcat.max-threads` is for the internal tomcat pool for handling incoming requests. The one you use is to define a `TaskExecutor` to execute background tasks asyncronous.

Comment: @M.Deinum so the total number of threads executing on JVM in case every thread is busy, should be tomcat max threads + task executor pool (and garbage collection etc, ofc). Right?

Comment: Another related post by @M.Deinum  for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126131/server-tomcat-max-threads-vs-corepoolsize-vs-spring-datasource-tomcat-max

Comment: Hmm I should keep track of all my answers :)